# Understanding Simple XML Parser - New File Output - Java

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, simple-framework

I am trying to learn how to use the Simple XML Framework as detailed in this thread : [Best practices for parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166862/best-practises-for-parsing-xml).

I am using the following code :

```
public class SimpleXMLParserActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    Example example = new Example("Example message", 123);
    File result = new File("example.xml");

    try {
        Log.d("Start", "Starting Serializer");
        serializer.write(example, result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Self", "Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I am having a problem understanding the line

```
File result = new File("example.xml");
```

1) Does this line create a new file in my app called example.xml ? If so where is this file located.

2) Or does this line look for an existing file called example.xml and then add to it ? If so where should the example.xml file be placed in my app bundle so that it can be found. I do notice at the moment I am getting an error message :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /example.xml (Read-only file system)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
File result = new File("example.xml")
```

This line will just store the filename "example.xml" in a new `File` object. There is no check if that file actually exists and it does not try to create it either.

A file without specifying an absolute path (starting with `/` like `new File("/sdcard/example.xml")`) is considered to be in the current working directory which I guess is `/` for Android apps (-> `/example.xml (Read-only file system)`)

I guess `serializer.write(example, result);` tries to create the actual file for your but fails since you can't write to '/'.

You have to specify a path for that file. There are several places you can store files, e.g.

- [Context#getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29) will give you a place in your app's home directory (`/data/data/your.package/files/`) where only you can read / write - without extra permission.
- [Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) will give you the general primary storage thing (might be `/sdcard/` - but that's very different for devices). To write here you'll need the [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.
- there are more places available in Environment that are more specialized. E.g. for media files, downloads, caching, etc.
- there is also [Context#getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) for app private (big) files you want to store on the external storage (something like `/sdcard/Android/data/your.package/`)

to fix your code you could do

```
File result = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "example.xml");
```

---

Edit: either use the provided mechanisms to get an existing directory (preferred but you are limited to the folders you are supposed to use):

```
// via File - /data/data/your.package/app_assets/example.xml
File outputFile = new File(getDir("assets", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), "example.xml");
serializer.write(outputFile, result);

// via FileOutputStream - /data/data/your.package/files/example.xml
FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("example.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
serializer.write(outputStream, result);
```

or you may need to create the directories yourself (hackish way to get your app dir but it should work):

```
File outputFile = new File(new File(getFilesDir().getParentFile(), "assets"), "example.xml");
outputFile.mkdirs();
serializer.write(outputFile, result);
```

Try to avoid specifying full paths like `"/data/data/com.simpletest.test/assets/example.xml"` since they might be different on other devices / Android versions. Even the `/` is not guaranteed to be `/`. It's safer to use `File.separatorChar` instead if you have to.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the code to : File result = new File("/data/data/com.simpletest.test/assets/example.xml"); However I am now getting an error that the file cannot be found ?

Comment: see edit in answer. You probably need to create the `assets` folder first or use one of the other (better) ways.

Answer (score 0):

What I read on the Android pages, I see it creates a file with that name:

[File constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29)

I think it writes it to the /data/data/**packagname** directory

edit: the 'packagename' was not shown in the tekst above. I put it between brackets. :s

Comment: edited it. the packagename directory is for the current application

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions to do it cleanly :

1. use openFileOutput to write a private file in the application private directory (which could be located in the internal memory or the external storage if the app was moved there). See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) for a snippet
2. or use the [File constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) to create the File anywhere your app has write access. This is if you want to store the file on the SDCard for example. Instantiating a file doesn't create it on the file system, unless you start writiung to it (with FileOutputStream for example)

I'd recommend approach 1, it's better for users because these files get erased when your app is uninstalled. If the file is large, then using the External Storage is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving to `/sdcard/example.xml`.