# which is better way to get an xml returned from web request for parsing

Tags: android

***I need to read an xml output returned from a php file through a web request in my android app.***

Hence, I have used Asynctask to read the xml file as byte by byte storing in a byte type array in background 
thread and then put the array in a text file. After completing the async task, I have used SAX perser to parse
the xml reading from the text file.

There is another way to do the same thing as below where complete xml is stored in a String variable:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.abcdefgh./abc/efg.php");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Here line variable contains the whole xml as a long string. **Could any one explain which one is better/effecient from above two procedure to do the job ......?**

Comment: Following Link helpful for you. [Android XML parsing][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166862/best-practices-for-parsing-xml

Comment: @hardik joshi I have my doubts about that, especially, "you should use Simple XML for all your XML needs onAndroid". Why indeed SHOULD I?

Comment: Actually, I am emphasizing on the reading of xml from web. Is it better to use AsynTask to read xml or the second technique that I described in the post.........?

Comment: You have to use something like AsyncTask anyway, because starting from ICS doing http on UI thread results in an exception. You have to put that code of yours into your AsyncTask. If you don't want AsyncTask you may use Executor passing a Callable to it, waiting for the Future.isDone... but anyway net operations must be on a separate thread

Comment: thanks @Alex. I have got the point which I was searching for. But I have found reading xml through AsyncTask is much slower than other.... as I am reading the xml byte by byte.......

Answer (score 0):

Normally they use a `Reader` on the `Entity`'s `InputStream`

Comment: This answer could be more helpful ... how about providing a simple example or a link to a similar question on [SO].