# In android is doing XPath evaluate or Pull parser faster?

Tags: android, xml

There is a remote xml file and I need to get set of xml nodes from it and show in an activity. One way is to download it completely and then do an xpath evaluate and get node set as follows

```
// using node I can drill further down to collect my relevant info 
NodeList names = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("/library/artists/name", new InputSource(new FileReader(getDowloadedXMLFileLocation())), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The other way is to use a pull parser which would be a bit more code I guess to do a simple job to extract a nodeset . I am wondering which method performs better in memory and speed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customized code versus a generic solution, equates to high performance versus ease of use.

`XPath` (and `XLST`, and `JDOM` etc) will construct a DOM like model, and iterate it. This will take more RAM and CPU. XPath is easy, but can be really slow for large files. Also it requires you to have the complete file at hand. Use this for small files.

`PullParser` on other hand is like reading a file only at places you are interested, skipping the rest. Also, only one node is loaded in RAM at a time. There are no limits on how large the input file is, or is it fully available or being streamed over a medium. Use this for large or streamed files.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent answer I found at [Best practices for parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166862/best-practices-for-parsing-xml)

You can also use XmlPullParser to parse xml. But I suggest if possible, use json instead of XML, which decrease your memory and Google provide its wrapper mechanism in [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Overview) which is best at all.

Links.

1) http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I can not change data from xml to any other, its third party. When we use xpath is it internally using DOM  or sax ?

Comment: what I found is "XPath is Originally motivated by a desire to provide a common syntax and behavior model between XPointer and XSLT, subsets of the XPath query language are used in other W3C specifications such as XML Schema, XForms and the Internationalization Tag Set (ITS)."